# how the browser execute this javascript code: window.location.href="url"

Tags: javascript, window, location

```
  $("#retrieve-cancel-reservation").click(function(){
       window.location.href="reservation.php?action_type=retrieve";
       $('#reservation_bar').css('display','none')
   });
```

**there is div,id=reservation_bar in the redirect link page.
But $('#reservation_bar').css('display','none') have no effect at the end.
It seems that i make mistakes about how the javascript code to execute .**

**Does anyone can explain how the browser execute those code above?

## Why the display=none is ont work? thanks a lot.**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can alter the CSS of another page, which is essentially what you are doing. I would keep the window.location redirect, and then hide $('#reservation_bar') on the new page on load. Include this on the new page:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#reservation_bar').css('display','none');
});
```

Comment: thank you,your code is work.what confused me is that how the browser to execute the javascript.